# enable wpautop filter on single posts only

Tags: wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

I've added the following to my wordpress themes functions.php file:

```
//disable wpautop filter
remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter ('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');
```

Which strips out all those pesky `<p> </p>` tags wordpress wraps around everything!

However, I was wondering if there was a way to do this ONLY on non-single pages (eg: home, archive, category, author etc). I want to disable wpautop on everything except single posts and pages... possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function get_rid_of_wpautop(){
  if(!is_singular()){
    remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop');
    remove_filter ('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');
  }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'get_rid_of_wpautop' );
```

Add that to your theme's `functions.php` file.